# ExpandableListView shows same ChildViews for every GroupView

Tags: android, expandablelistview, baseadapter

I have implemented an `ExpandableListView` and a `BaseExpandableListAdapter`. I want to display a list of GroupObjects. Every GroupObject (Top-items in ExpandableList) has an ArrayList of 3 ChildObjects (Child-items in ExpandableList).

I am using the viewHolder-pattern.
The GroupObjects are displayed correctly. Once I expand the first GroupObject, `getChildView()` gets called 3 times and displays its ChildObjects correctly.

But as soon as I expand another GroupObject, `getChildView()` returns the ChildObjects of the **first GroupObject**. Since the convertView of the second call is not null, it always returns the same ChildObjects.

Here is some Code:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ChildObject childobject = (ChildObject)getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    ChildViewholder childViewholder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        childViewholder = new ChildViewholder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (!childobject.isReserved()) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childobject_free,
                    parent, false);
            childViewHolder.layout = (RelativeLayout)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.childobject_free_layout);

        } else {
            final Reservation reservation = childobject.getReservation();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.childobject_reserved, parent, false);
            childViewHolder.layout = (RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.reserved_layout);

            childViewHolder.reservationImage = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.reservationImage);
            childViewHolder.reservationName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.reservationName);
            childViewHolder.buttonFinish = (ImageButton)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.finishButton);
            childViewHolder.buttonCancel = (ImageButton)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
            childViewHolder.progressBar = (ProgressBar)convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.reservationProgress);

            childObject.getTimer().setProgressBar(childViewHolder.progressBar);
            childViewHolder.reservationName.setText(reservation.getName());
            childViewHolder.reservationImage.setImageBitmap(reservation.getBitmap());

            childViewHolder.buttonFinish.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DrawerClickHandler.finishReservation(reservation);
                }
            });

            childViewHolder.buttonCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    DrawerClickHandler.cancelReservation(reservation);
                }
            });

        }

        convertView.setTag(childViewholder);

    }else{
        childViewholder = (ChildViewholder)convertView.getTag();
    }

        childViewHolder.groupPosition = groupPosition;
        childViewHolder.childPosition = childPosition;

        return convertView;
}
```

The convertView is only null on the first 3 calls of `getChildView()`.

Let me know if you need more code.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your full code for `getChildView`?

Comment: It is basically the full code. I just left out the part where I set the attributes for the components of childViewHolder

Comment: Yeah..that part is important

Comment: ok I edited it. let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: First of all, you're setting the data to the child view **only** when the convert view is `null`(so the data needs to be set outside of the `if` condition testing for a null convert view), when the convert view is not null you end up with data from previous rows. Secondly, that is not how you handle two types of rows in an `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: @MartinGolpashin @Luksprog is right. You are not setting the data when `convertView` is `not null`. And that is not the way to handle two types of rows. You need to make use of `getChildType()` and `getChildTypeCount()` of `BaseExpandableListAdapter` class.